# how to get battery status of a bluetooth headphone in c#

Tags: c#, windows, bluetooth, device, headphones

I have a pair of Bluetooth headphones and I want to retrieve its battery status and especially the level of remaining charge in my Windows application. I searched a lot but I couldn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Try with this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/get-battery-info

Comment: Were you able to find anything?

Comment: unfortunately no